# Laravel: problem when logging in user object via AJAX request

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to change my login to OTP.

I will send the user a token via SMS. The user enters the token and submits the for verification in the backend via AJAX.

This is the function that verifies the code:

```
function verify_token(Request $request){
    $token = LoginToken::where('token' , $request->input('token') )->first();
    if(!$token)
        jerror("cant find the token !") ;

    $user = User::findOrFail($token->user_id);
    Auth::loginUsingId($token->user_id);

    echo json_encode(['success'=>1 , 'redirect'=>URL('/')]);
}
```

Here is my AJAX call, please ignore syntax errors:

```
function vrify(){
    let form = {
        token : $('#token').val() , 
        //csrf token 
    };

    $.post( '{{route("verify")}}' ,  form , function(data){
        data = $.parseJson(data);
        if(data.success == 1 )
        {
            document.location = data.redirect ; 
        }
    })
}
```

Even though verify is successful, the user is not logged in after the redirect.

If I send data as normal form POST, and change the last line of verify function to:

```
return redirect(URL('/'));
```

It works fine!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there value exists in $user?

Comment: Will refreshing the page log in the user? The redirect is basically only redirecting the the AJAX request not the browser page you are on. So instead after a successful verification in your JavaScript do the redirect.

Comment: @Ranjeet yes , i've checked it ... also form which works find is using this code

Comment: @Michael when its ajax call , i'll return the redirect address in the backend response and js will redirect the user to that address after ajax call is done ,  which dont work  ....  when i use a normal html form , sending user browser to verification function and redirecting user after verification it works ... i've added js code to my question to clarify

Comment: Is your verification route and the URL where you are redirecting to both in the web middleware group?

Comment: @mdexp well i have a clientMiddleware which reads some general data from db and injects them to view ... they both are in that middle ware

Comment: Can you post your routes (and specify if they are defined in web.php or api.php or any other file) or the relevant output of `php artisan route:list`? The fact is that sessions are started with the `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` middleware. This is done by default in the `web` middleware group. If your route is outside that group and doesn't have that particular middleware applied to it you can't interact with sessions through different http requests

Comment: Have you checked your browser's network console? Is the AJAX request sent properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `return response()->json(['success' => 1, 'redirect' => URL('/')]);` rather than `echo`.

Furthermore, try `Auth::login($token)` instead of `Auth::loginUsingId($token->user_id)`.

Also please note that by default, `Auth::loginUsingId()` takes primary key. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#authenticating-users)

Comment: @hretic You're welcome. That was because your function was never returning earlier. Updating the answer to make it clearer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Change your line

```
 echo json_encode(['success'=>1 , 'redirect'=>URL('/')]);
```

to

```
return response()->json(['success' => 1, 'redirect' => URL('/')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set cookie. because after login laravel set cookie from headers and check authenticate from it.

Comment: yeah i think its has something to do with cookie , but i assume laravel should take care of that

Answer (score 0):

If the user is not logged after redirect you are basically not storing his credentials, thus having no login session.
As @omidkhaleghi said you can set a *httponly* cookie containing the token, which will be used in your request as authentication /middleware plays its role here as well/ 
As for checking if an user is logged you can just check if the cookie exist and if the token valid.

Also check [this](https://codeforgeek.com/mobile-number-verification-using-laravel/) out. I think that can help you.